# Functional derivative of the sum of a product

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, functional-analysis, derivatives, permutations

Suppose I have a product like the following:
$$P(A)=\sum_{i_1=0}^{\infty}\ldots\sum_{i_n=0}^{\infty}c_{i_1}\ldots c_{i_k} A(x^1_{1})\ldots A(x^1_{i_1})\ldots A(x^n_1)\ldots A(x_{i_n}^n)\\
=c_{0}^n+c_{1}c_0^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^nA(x_1^k) +c_2c_0^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n A(x^k_1)A(x^k_2)+ c_1^2 c_{0}^{n-2}\sum_{i\neq j=1}^n A(x^i_1)A(x^j_1)+\ldots$$
where I have written explicitly the first three terms (all $i_k=0$ or one $i_k=1$ with all other zero and one $i_k=2$ with all other zero or two $i_a=i_b=1$ with all other zero).

Now suppose I want to write  the $m$-th functional derivative
$\frac{\delta}{\delta A(y_1)}\ldots \frac{\delta}{\delta A(y_m)}P(A)\rvert_{A=0}$ calculated in zero. The derivative is defined as:
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta A(y_1)} A(x) = \delta(x-y_1)$$
I know that a product
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta A(y_1)}\ldots \frac{\delta}{\delta A(y_n)}\prod_{i=1}^{n}A(x_i)=\sum_{\sigma\in P_n}\prod_{i=1}^n\delta(x_{\sigma_i}-y_{i})$$
where $\sigma$ are permutations of the indices $P_n = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and I can write $P(A)$ as:

$$P(A)=\sum_{i_1=0}^{\infty}\ldots\sum_{i_n=0}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{n}c_{i_j}\prod_{k=1}^{i_j}A(x_k^j)$$
However, now I don't know how to write $\frac{\delta}{\delta A(y_1)}\ldots \frac{\delta}{\delta A(y_m)}P(A)\rvert_{A=0}$